# display available options without completing

Tags: bash, autocomplete, compgen

I was wondering if it's possible to make `compgen` (`complete`) only display possible options without completing.

for example with `COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "--option1 --option2" -- $cur ))` `--option1 --option2` will be suggested but `--` will be added to my command line. Can I get rid of `--`

I took a look at `compgen`'s options but I cannot find the one that can help. I don't want to do any hack ( for eg displaying options first and then `COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "" -- $cur ))`)

Comment: `compgen` *does* only display the completions. Putting them into `COMPREPLY` is what completes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but running `compgen -W "--option1 --option2" -- $cur` the shell turns into a mess, how can I get the options above my command line as usual ?

Comment: After `cli + Tab Tab` I want the options `--option1 --option2` to be displayed but I don't want `--` to be added to my command line (`cli`). `compgen` has an option `-P` to add a prefix to displayed options,  I'll test it.

Comment: Have you get this working? I have exactly same problem