# Simulate Bash's COMPREPLY response without actually completing it

Tags: bash, autocomplete, bash-completion, compgen

### Steps to reproduce

- Create directory on tmp, add 1 file inside.

  ```
  mkdir /tmp/testdir && touch /tmp/testdir/examplefile
  ```
- Paste below script on `/tmp/completion.sh`

  ```
  # BEGIN AUTOCOMPLETE
  function _foo_complete() {
  local comnum cur opts
  [[ "${COMP_WORDS[@]}" == *"-"* ]] && comnum=2 || comnum=1;
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  opts="--help --restart -h -r"
  if (( COMP_CWORD > comnum )); then
   COMPREPLY=( $(for filename in "/tmp/testdir/"*; do echo ${filename##*/}; done) )
   return
  fi
  if [[ ${cur} == -* ]]; then
   COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
   return 0
  else
   COMPREPLY=( $(for filelist in /tmp/testdir/"$2"*; do echo ${filelist##*/}; done) )
  fi
  }
  complete -F _foo_complete foo.sh
  # END AUTOCOMPLETE
  ```
- Source it then.

  ```
  . /tmp/completion.sh
  ```

---

#### Expected result

```
$ foo.sh --restart examplefile <tab><tab>
examplefile           
$ foo.sh --restart examplefile <tab><tab>
examplefile        
$ foo.sh --restart examplefile <tab><tab>
examplefile     
$ foo.sh --restart examplefile <tab><tab>
```

#### What happen instead

```
$ foo.sh --restart examplefile <tab><tab> examplefile <tab><tab> examplefile <tab><tab> examplefile <tab><tab> examplefile <tab><tab> examplefile
```

I want the suggestion to appear as possible completion, but without actually completing it (for display purposes). This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56582763/12289283), but to this date no answer is given.

#### Regarding `-o nosort`

I look into that option and it's only available at Bash 4.4+, I tried on my 16.04 machine and it fail. Looking for more *global*ish solution

Comment: Do you expect it to always just list all the files in the current directory? i.e. if you type `./myscript /usr/bin<<tab><tab>` it shouldn't list `/usr` or `/usr/bin`, but rather the current directory?

Comment: @root I have updated the question. The completion file is created to only take file from hard coded directory.

Comment: Why is there a bounty on this question? @pynexj hack that adds a blank to `COMPREPLY` (which could also be the empty string `''` instead) should be good enough no?

Comment: @Frevadona I forgot to mention, `-o nosort` is only available at Bash 4.4+, I tried on my 16.04 machine and it fail. Looking for more "global"ish solution.

Comment: Why do you insist on relying on COMPREPLY when you know COMPREPLY will always allow anything that user "tabs" against its values to do a completion? Shouldn't you be producing an output instead?

Comment: @konsolebox That's okay, but can you show how to exactly do that ? At the moment I can't think any action that will show directory content by pressing tab

Comment: @konsolebox -- he does not want a command to "output" a list of files or something. he wants the files to be automatically "displayed" (but without actually completing) when pressing TAB (in an interactive shell) as in `some-command <TAB><TAB>`.

Comment: @Liso you may try my workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following `compspec.sh` (based on OP's code):

```
function _foo_complete()
{
    local comnum cur opts

    [[ "${COMP_WORDS[@]}" == *"-"* ]] && comnum=2 || comnum=1;

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    opts="--help --restart -h -r"

    if (( COMP_CWORD > comnum )); then
        COMPREPLY=( $(for filename in "/tmp/testdir/"*; do echo ${filename##*/}; done) )
        if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
            #
            # you can try COMPREPLY+=( zzz ) and see what's happening
            #
            COMPREPLY+=( ' ' )
        fi
        return
    fi

    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur} ) )
        return 0
    else
        COMPREPLY=( $( for filelist in /tmp/testdir/"$2"*; do echo ${filelist##*/}; done ) )
    fi
}

complete -F _foo_complete foo.sh
```

[image]

---

#### UPDATE:

> is it possible to move the empty string to end of completion, so it doesn't look like there are empty space?

You can use `complete -o nosort` <sup>(requires Bash 4.4+)</sup> if you can sort the completion candidates all by yourself.

Comment: Hello, it works great. If it's not too much to ask, how to make response/possible completion aligned to left and not center ? Thanks

Comment: nothing is perfect. it's good enough to be good enough.

Comment: Then is it possible to move the empty string to end of completion, so it doesn't look like there are empty space? Ive been looking for that

Answer (score 3):

You can try this trick; depending on your OS, this might work for you:

<sup>**note**: I stripped the completion function down to the relevant <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality</sup>

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /tmp/testdir && touch /tmp/testdir/examplefile

_foo_complete() {
    local dirpath=/tmp/testdir
    local nullglob=$( shopt -q nullglob && echo true || echo false )

    $nullglob || shopt -s nullglob
    COMPREPLY=( "$dirpath"/* )
    $nullglob || shopt -u nullglob

    COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]#"$dirpath"/}" )

    [ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ] && COMPREPLY+=( $'\xC2\xA0' )
}
complete -F _foo_complete foo.sh
```

**Postscript:**

It's basically the same idea than @pynexj [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548648/3387716): adding a second, invisible, element to `COMPREPLY`, thus disabling the  <kbd>Tab</kbd> auto-completion while keeping the <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> listing.

Now the problem is that bash sorts `COMREPLY` automatically, so, with the ASCII `space` character being numerically the first `printable` character, it will be displayed as the first column of the listing.

To work around it I tried almost all other white-space characters in the UTF-8 charset and they all get sorted to the same rank than the ASCII `space` character; all but the `NON-BREAKING-SPACE`, that's what I'm using here.

The fix is not full proof because there's a lot of UTF-8 characters that will get sorted after it, and above all, it gets different treatments depending on the OS: some `sort` implementations will give it the same rank than the ASCII `space` character, while others won't. Think about it, what is `NON-BREAKING-SPACE` conceptually? **It's a white-space, but also like a letter at the same time!**

Comment: I can't get your solution to work, could you test your script with my requirement/code I posted in my question ?  However that html encoding it's working nicely.

Comment: `0xc2a0` is utf8 [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) so the idea is similar. not sure if it works in non-utf8 locale and not sure if it would always be the last one when being sorted.

Comment: @pynexj: Yeah, I've been trying different approaches and I now can say that there is no other way to get the expected output. Using `&nbsp;` have its limitations, but as long as the filename starts with an ASCII character and the OS supports UTF8 then it will work.

Comment: @Liso The code was only illustrating the TAB TAB completion. I'll update it for implementing the functionalities of the original function (not possible today though)

Comment: just tried but for me (`en_US.UTF-8`) the nbsp also comes first when displaying the completion candidates. what locale are you using?

Comment: you can also try with `printf '%s\n' aaa zzz $'\xc2\xa0' | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort`.

Comment: @pynexj I tried LANG and LC_ALL with `C` `en_US.UTF-8` `fr_FR.UTF-8` `es_ES.UTF-8`, all of them are working fine

Comment: maybe it's OS dependent. my result (on macos Big Sur) is not the same. see https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsoTC.png

Comment: @pynexj It seems that the sorting is different from OS to OS. Using `en_US-utf-8` as LANG/LC_ALL, it works on macOS Mojave/Catalina, FreeBSD 11/12, RedHat 7/8, but **not** on Solaris 11.3/11.4 and macOS BigSur

Answer (score 0):

Edited code corresponding to your complete requirements:

```
_test(){
   COMPREPLY=(                                                                                                                      
      $( [[ "$2" == -* ]] && compgen -W'-a -ab -c' -- "$2" \                                                                
      || [[ -d test ]] && compgen -W'$(basename -a test/*)' -- "$2" | grep -v -w -f <(printf "%s\n" "${COMP_WORDS[@    ]}:1:((COMP_CWORD-1))"))
   )
}

if the test directory doesn't exist completion would work with current directory contents so we have to check it

options can be used multiple times as you didn't specify it.
```

1
2 complete -F _test test

Comment: 1. Yes, no duplicate file/option on argument; 2. Also yes, if user wish to include options; 3. File from current directory should be presented upon pressing `tab`.

Comment: it's important to get the requirements right or it's  wild goose chase, 1 and 3 were absent, and 2 is not defined enough; should 2 be active when the user starts an argument with '-' or should those option be listed with the possible files, not duplicated, from the current directory and the specific directory? should the options be listed first or sorted like the default completion does?

Comment: If user start argument with `-`, it should bring argument `--restart` `--help` without listing possible files, if `-` is not present-- then list all (no duplicate/repeated) possible files. Meaning if user already pick `file1`, then on next option he shall not pick that again.

Comment: just to be 100% sure, when you wrote files from the "current directory" did you mean from the current directory plus the test/ directory, only the former? only the later?

Comment: The latter, only from test directory

Comment: I get the following testing your snippets: `foo.sh --bash: @    : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "@    ")`.

Comment: Either you copied it wrong https://pastebin.com/2xAA4qSR or it can be bash version related, mine is:

GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>